# Importing a .csv with urls and process them (PYTHON)

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, lxml, python-2.x

I am working on a scrip that will import a list of urls and then check some things in the source code. I need help on importing a .csv and processing it, if anyone can help here is a part of the code

```
from lxml import html
import csv

def main():
with open('urls.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    urls = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

for url in urls:

    doc = html.parse(url)
linkziel = 'http://dandydiary.de/de'
if doc.xpath('//a[@href=$url]', url=linkziel):
    for anchor_node in doc.xpath('//a[@href=$url]', url=linkziel):
        if anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "sidebar")]'):
            print 'Sidebar'
        elif anchor_node.xpath('./parent::div[contains(@class, "widget")]'):
            print 'Sidebar'           
        elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "comment")]'):
            print 'Kommentar'
        elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@id, "comment")]'):
            print 'Kommentar'
        elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "foot")]'):
            print "Footer"
        elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@id, "foot")]'):
            print "Footer" 
        elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "post")]'):
            print "Contextual"         
        else:
            print 'Unidentified Link'          
else:
    print 'Link is Dead'

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Instead of specifying just one url, I want to use a csv that will be ran trough (I am using Python 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a `input.csv` file with a url on every new line:

```
http://de.wikipedia.org
http://spiegel.de
http://www.vickysmodeblog.com/
```

Then, you can just read it into a list via [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module and iterate over it:

```
import csv
from lxml import html


with open('input.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    urls = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

for url in urls:
    print url

    doc = html.parse(url)
    linkziel = 'http://dandydiary.de/de'
    if doc.xpath('//a[@href=$url]', url=linkziel):
        for anchor_node in doc.xpath('//a[@href=$url]', url=linkziel):
            if anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "sidebar")]'):
                print 'Sidebar'
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./parent::div[contains(@class, "widget")]'):
                print 'Sidebar'
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "comment")]'):
                print 'Kommentar'
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@id, "comment")]'):
                print 'Kommentar'
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "foot")]'):
                print "Footer"
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@id, "foot")]'):
                print "Footer"
            elif anchor_node.xpath('./ancestor::div[contains(@class, "post")]'):
                print "Contextual"
            else:
                print 'Unidentified Link'
    else:
        print 'Link is Dead'
```

The output for it is:

```
http://de.wikipedia.org
Link is Dead
http://spiegel.de
Link is Dead
http://www.vickysmodeblog.com/
Contextual
```

Comment: thanks, that works fine. But there is still a problem, I have 3 input urls in the csv and it does run trough them, but instead of telling me that 2 urls do not contain the link and 1 does (sidebar for example) it will only give out one line (instead of 3)

Comment: Then, sounds like a problem with your xpaths. Speaking about `http://www.vickysmodeblog.com/`: it correctly finds the `a` node, but it's not located in the div with `sidebar` in the class.

Comment: I have updated the code preview in my mainpost, maybe this helps to clarify

Comment: it seems as its only reading the last line inside the csv, not all of them each.

Comment: Nope, I've checked - `print url` prints every url from csv. Do you see it?

Comment: yes, it does print the urls correctly, but instead of giving me 2 times the notification that "link dead" and once "contextual" it gives me just "contextual" and that is only if the correct sourceurl is the last line in the csv. Output in my IDE looks like this: http://s1.directupload.net/images/130502/znrclg5u.jpg (the csv just contains the url, there is no additional column

Comment: I've updated the answer with full code I'm using and the output I get. Looks right: there is no `http://dandydiary.de/de` link on `http://de.wikipedia.org` and `http://spiegel.de` pages. Check if it helps.

Comment: thanks alot, thats exactly what it should do :) Ill vote the answere up once I got the rights to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module which you might use for importing the list.